# float64array in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm using [speakjs](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js) in [my webapp](http://sw.webcrumpet.com) and in chrome and firefox it runs without errors, however on attempt to run the speakjs client in safari I receive the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Float64Array
```

I have attempted searching through the js and replacing `Float64Array` with `Float32Array` but to no avail.

How can i go about solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Update Safari to the current version. It implements `Float64Array`.

I don't have an answer for getting Safari 5.x to work with code that uses it. I am currently struggling with that.

Update: Luckily for me my usecase of Float64Array came from the emscripten box2d build. Simply replacing `Float64Array` with `Float32Array` did the trick for me for Safari 5! It made it work on older versions of Firefox (I tested version 10) also.

Comment: I don't understand why safari didn't support it earlier :\, there /must/ be some kind of workaround

Comment: I have tried two typed array shims already. One of them didn't work. The other flat-out crashed MobileSafari.